# How to pass question mark as parameter to history.pushState("","","?like_this")

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

http://jsfiddle.net/leathan/jDKP5/22/

Basically I want to do that but instead of test=yes i want it to be "?test=yes".

If I try `windows.history.pushState("","","?test=yes")` it simply doesnt work as seen in the above jsfiddle modified to include a question mark.

I tried url encoding & escaping, it still didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.history.pushState("","","?test=yes")`will do it. See http://jsfiddle.net/pc0Lhkuc/, the problem is `location.pathname` is a DOMString containing an initial '/' followed by the path of the URL, you should use `location.search` instead, which is a DOMString containing a '?' followed by the parameters or "querystring" of the URL.

Comment: such a fast answer and really explained to me what was going on thanks alot.